# Change profile picture button in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create change profile picture button like the image below. I'm a newbie in ios, I have an idea of create a view with those button and make the background opacity to 50. I'm just wondering if xcode or ios has a default function same as the shown image below.

[image]

Comment: Check this out. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You would be better off using the builtin `UIActionSheet` class

Comment: Thanks for that..I know now what i'm going to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
  UIActionSheet *action=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Change Profile Picture" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Remove Current Photo" otherButtonTitles:@"Import From Facebook",@"Import From Twitter",@"Take Photo",@"Choose From Library", nil];

 [action showInView:self.view];
```

And use below code for actionsheet button click action.

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {
    }
    else if (buttonIndex==1) 
    {
    }
    ...
}
```